# TelescopeJs data-zones

Tags: meteor, telescope

I want to add `postThumbnail` zone inside the `top` zone. I tried doing this

`Telescope.modules.add("top","postThumbnail");`

It did not work. Can anyone give me solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

postThumbnail is the module. post_thumbnail is the template. Just a syntax error at this point, but the rest should work fine.

`Telescope.modules.add` needs an object as second argument, try this :

```
Telescope.modules.add("top", {
  template: "post_thumbnail",
  // you may need to tweak the order value
  order: 10
});
```

https://telescope.readme.io/docs/template-modules#adding-a-module

Comment: I tried that but it wont work, `postThumbnail` is an zone not Template.@saimeunt